# django forms is_valid() always returns false

Tags: django-forms

I have a real annoying issue with `form.is_valid()` always returning false on one of my forms, and this only happens when I manually define fields in a modelform, and in particular use ModelChoiceField and ModelMultipleChoiceFields passing in my own custom querysets

```
location = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, widget = forms.Select(), queryset = Location.objects.none())
```

I cannot find much in the way of good documentation about `ModelForm.is_valid()`, and essentially, if I don't call it everything works fine. I am happy with this except for the fact that every Django forms example makes this call to `is_valid()`.

So I guess my question is:

1. Is it okay to not check if a form is valid?
2. If it is not, any ideas why it is always returning false?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find out the specific validation errors for your form, which will possibly give you more information about the specific error: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: Oh yes, I can see i was being rather dumb here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking your if your form is valid and then you can go from there but what I found worked when I was having the same problem was:

```
def add(request):
form = SearchForm()
add_form = AddForm()
if request.method == 'GET':
    add_form = AddForm(request.GET)
    if add_form.is_valid():
        return render_to_response('inventory_app/add.html', {'form': form, 'add_form': add_form, 'message': 'Sent Sucessfully'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else: 
        return render_to_response('inventory_app/add.html', {'form': form, 'add_form': add_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

With an emphasis on the line before the add_form.is_valid line:

```
add_form = AddForm(request.GET)
    if add_form.is_valid():
```

If you don't request the form then the .is_valid statement will always return false.